# Accented letters with Firefox and Chrome on MAC OS

Tags: asp.net, macos, firefox

i have this problem:
i have this tag for upload a file

```
<div id="form-attachments">
   <input type="file" name="attachFile" id="attachFile"/>
</div>
```

and i recover the value like this

```
$("#attachFile").change(function () {
  var file = document.getElementById('attachFile').files[0];
  uploadFile(file);
});

function uploadFile(file) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('IDNotifica', $('#IDNotifica').val());
    formData.append('relata', $('#fileTipoRelata').val());
    var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
    //var bool = checkNome(filename);
    //if (!bool)
    //    return false;
    $("#loadingFile").fadeIn();
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#PathAggiungiAllegati').val(),  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
        xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: completeHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        //    jqXHR.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=iso-8859-1');
        //}
    });

}
```

Windows is ok, but in MAC OS, when the value of file uploaded arrive at server, i have a check control for block a file with special char (also accetented letters) but this check don't detect the accented letters from Mac Client.
I have try more methods(convert to utf8, change charset, insert a check control at client side ecc..) but i think that the problem live in tag `
(this problem is present only on Firefox and Chrome, in Safari is ok)

```
<div id="form-attachments">
     <input type="file" name="attachFile" id="attachFile"/>
</div>`
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What has C got to do with this question? Please don't spam tags.

Comment: there's not C, but C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is described precisely in Stackoverflow post:

[Strange font encoding in all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076418/strange-font-encoding-in-all-browsers)

In general this website does not render correctly in Firefox whereas in Chrome it is okay:

https://goout.net/cs/muzea/apple-museum/wucb/

Actual results:

The font is rendered incorrectly.

Expected results:

The font should be rendered correctly.